# Angular Image cropping

Tags: angular

I am trying to upload a file and crop the image displayed on screen but I keep seeing this error all the time - Any Idea?

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setImage' of undefined
    at FileReader.myReader.onloadend
```

I am setting setImage(Image) in File Upload method as below but it still gives me issue -

```
fileChangeListener($event) {
    myReader.onloadend = function (loadEvent:any) {
    image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
    that.cropper1.setImage(image);
  };
}
```

Comment: I know it's not what you're directly asking but you might like using this library, I love it = https://alyle.io/components/image-cropper

Comment: Thanks but we are looking for Angular plugins only.

Comment: That is an angular one :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileChangeListener($event) {
  myReader.onloadend = (loadEvent:any) => {   // replace function with => arrow 
  image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
  this.cropper1.setImage(image);            // that should be this
 };
}
```